# How can I copy columns from layer 1 to layer 2?

Tags: qgis, layers, fields-attributes

I have two layers, the first layer is pipe: that has some fields (column) title like : length, id, material. Also I have another layer that is empty (without any fields). How can I copy fields (column) title from layer 1 to layer 2?

I am new to QGIS.

Comment: Why don't you just create a copy of the layer with the attributes? Then copy-paste the features from the layer without attributes into the new one.

Comment: Are you familiar with a plugin called "Table Manager"? I've found it quite useful when managing field names in QGIS attribute tables.

Comment: @underdark THANKS FOR YOUR RESPOND, actually let me ask a general issue, for example I have 2 layer ( polylines) with different fields, how can I copy/paste fields titles?

Comment: @bwilkes frankly no, as I mentioned I am new at Qgis

Answer (score 3):

If you join two layers, the resulting layer will contain the columns of both input layers. Just join and then use "Save as ..." to save the result to a new file.